# Is it possible to mount associated path to WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I used `subst R: .` for a faster way to access a folder.

Is it possible to mount the `R:` "drive" to WSL? When I try running `sudo mkdir /mnt/r` then `sudo mount -t ntfs R: /mnt/r`, I am met with this error:

```
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume 'R:': No such file or directory

ntfs-3g 2017.3.23AR.3 integrated FUSE 28 - Third Generation NTFS Driver

Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on
Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson 

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com
```

Thanks in advance!

Asked the same question on StackOverflow but realized that wasn't the right place to do so...

Comment: Related: [superuser.com/a/1261563/990044](https://superuser.com/a/1261563/990044)

Comment: @Freddy Not really related, as this question is about `subst` mappings, which are not "real" drives (not even network drives, it seems) and cannot be "mounted".  The closest thing to `subst` is a `mount --bind`, which isn't even mentioned in that question/answer.

Comment: And by the way, @Justin-Chang, kudos for finding a good use for that nearly 40-year old `subst` command. It's been literally decades since I've seen it.  I had to look it up to be sure, but as I thought, it came about as a DOS 3.1 command before Windows was even a gleam in Gates' eye.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While WSL doesn't have *automatic* or even *direct* access to the `subst` drives, there are ways to map them.  There are several routes to go here, depending on your exact workflow.

The main things to remember are:

- In Linux, `sudo mount --bind . /mnt/r` is roughly equivalent to `subst R: .`.  If you're okay with just having the Linux equivalent, and you don't need to access the same drive letter under Windows, then this may be all you need.  You could even create a `subst` function in bash that would work pretty closely to that of Windows.
- That said, `bind` is probably overkill here.  You most likely just want a symlink, like `ln -s /mnt/c/Users/username ~/r`.  This doesn't require root as long as you have permissions to the target location.
- For mappings that you have created in Windows with `subst`, you can retrieve the `subst`ituted paths in Linux by calling out to PowerShell, like:  `powershell.exe -c subst`
- You can filter that down to just the R: mapping using `grep` and `sed`:  `powershell.exe -c "subst" | grep "^R" | sed "s/^R:\\\\: => //"` (in case there are multiple drives/directories `subst`ituted, find just the R: drive, then remove everything before the directory path).
- PowerShell returns an extra newline ("\r"), so you have to strip that with something like `tr -d "\r"`.
- You can convert a Windows path to the Linux/WSL equivalent with the `wslpath` command.

Put it all together, and you get the script that can turn your R: into `/mnt/r` (or `~/r` if that's more convenient):

```
rpath=$(powershell.exe -c "subst" | grep "^R" | sed "s/^R:\\\\: => //" | tr -d "\r")
sudo mount --bind $(wslpath "${rpath}") /mnt/r/
```

Or the equivalent with the `ln` instead.

Of course, you'll want to assign it to a function so it's easier to repeat.